# Convert HTML to PDF with required form fields in PHP

Tags: php, symfony, wkhtmltopdf

I have been using wkhtmltopdf successfully with PHP using KnpSnappyBundle in Symfony but it appears there is no way to set the form fields in the generated PDF to be required fields which is a deal breaker for our needs. It would be nice if wkhtmltopdf recognized the html Required attribute but it does not.

I have yet to find any libraries that support setting form fields as required. Any suggestions? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What kind of suggestions you are looking for?

Comment: ask your question more clear , show us your code , and tell us what have you done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[wkhtmtopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) is not yet capable of setting pdf form fields as required fields when converting html to pdf. Due to that limitation, [KnpLabs Snappy](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy) and therefore [KnpSnappyBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpSnappyBundle) cannot be used to set form fields as required because those libraries use wkhtmltopdf.

I still use KnpSnappy with wkhtmltopdf but am now using the [DocuSign Tabs API](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs) to create required fields and force users to fill out the forms through DocuSign as well.